# Point on a diameter of a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

$MN$ is a diameter of a circle $k(O;R)$. Point $T$ is chosen on $MN$ and the chord $PQ$ passes through $P$, so that $\measuredangle MNP=60^\circ,\measuredangle NPT=73^\circ$ and $PT=3$. Find the diameter of $k$.

[image]

When I drew a figure with GeoGebra, I discovered that $R\approx 2,53$. This can be useful (as a reference point).

Firstly, we have the metric relation $$MT\cdot TN=PT\cdot TQ$$ We only know $PT=3$, so I don't think this can be useful (at least for now).

Secondly, if we connect $M$ with $P$, triangle $MPN$ is a right triangle with angles 30-60-90, but I wasn't able to use this somehow.

Please give me any ideas for what to do next, that might lead toward the desired length.

Comment: Find $NP$ using law of sines given you know $PT$. $NP$ is equal to the radius of the circle.

Comment: @MathLover, thank you for the response! As far as I understand your idea is the same as Andrei's one. You suggest I use the law of sines for triangle $POT$. Please, see my comment under Andrei's answer.

Comment: No, directly in $\triangle NPT$. $\frac{\sin \angle {NTP}}{NP} = \frac{\sin 60^0}{3}$. That gives you $NP$. Now diameter is two times $NP$.

Comment: @MathLover, my point still holds. We have $$\dfrac{3}{\sin60^\circ}=\dfrac{R}{\sin47^\circ}\Rightarrow R=2\sqrt3\sin47^\circ.$$ As we don't know $\sin47^\circ$, can I leave the answer in this form?

Comment: Yes of course answer is the same and what Andrei says works too. Diameter is $4 \sqrt3 \sin 47^0$. You can either use a calculator and find $\sin 47^0$ or leave as it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** Connect $O$ with $P$. What are the angles in $\triangle NOP$? Find the angles in $\triangle TOP$. Use law of sines. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I got that $\measuredangle POT=120^\circ,\measuredangle TPO=13^\circ$ and $\measuredangle OTP=47^\circ$. Am I right? We don't know the exact trig values of $13^\circ$ and $47^\circ$. How am I supposed to use the law of sines?

Comment: $\sin 47^\circ=0.73135370161$. You use a calculator for that, or approximate it from a Taylor series around $45^\circ$.